# Delay appearance of buttons in sweetalert2

Tags: javascript, alert, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I am using [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io) to communicate some feedback to the user. This is a learning app, so, I want the feedback to persist for some time. I do not want to show any buttons immediately after the feedback is displayed because people have a tendency to just click on 'OK' or 'Cancel', without reading the text.

The number of characters in the feedback varies from screen to screen, so, I am using the timer parameter of sweetalert2 to be some multiple of the number of characters in the text. But, the timer feature is imperfect because people have different reading speeds. Ideally, I would want the 'OK' button to appear after the timer has timed out. Is there some sort of an API call I can make to dynamically change the property of the alert box?

```
swal({
        html: feedback,
        timer: feedback.length*50,
        showCloseButton: false,
        showCancelButton: false,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi to achive this you can use a set timeout function and call jQuery's .show() function on the buttons that you wish to show (Assuming you are ok with using jQuery).

The following code should help you out

```
swal({
        html: feedback,
        timer: feedback.length*50,
        showCloseButton: false,
        showCancelButton: false,
        showConfirmButton: false,
        allowOutsideClick: false,
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        $(".swal2-cancel").show();
        $(".swal2-confirm").show();
        $(".swal2-close").show();
    }, 3000);
```

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks! For anyone else who is seeing this, you may want to add the classes of the divs that contain swal2-confirm to the list of classes that are being shown. But, very nice method!

Comment: No problem, I am glad this helped you.

Comment: By the way which class did you mean? I can add it to the answer to help future users if you like.

Comment: I guess the containing divs depend on what exactly what options are used. In my case, it was the `.swal2-buttonswrapper` div

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any method to hide and show the buttons, but you can disable and enable them:

```js
swal({
  html: 'test',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,

  onOpen: function () {
    swal.disableButtons();
    setTimeout(swal.enableButtons, 'test'.length * 500) 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.9/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.9/sweetalert2.min.css">
```

or make them transparent:

```js
swal({
  html: 'test',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,

  onOpen: function () {
    var b = swal.getConfirmButton()
    b.style.opacity = 0
    b.disabled = true
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      b.disabled = false
      b.style.opacity = 1
    }, 'test'.length * 500) 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.9/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.9/sweetalert2.min.css">
```

or hide and show:

```js
swal({
  html: 'test',
  allowOutsideClick: false,
  allowEscapeKey: false,

  onOpen: function () {
    var b = swal.getConfirmButton()
    b.hidden = true
    b.disabled = true
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      b.disabled = false
      b.hidden = false
    }, 'test'.length * 500) 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.9/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/6.6.9/sweetalert2.min.css">
```

Comment: Am accepting @hayden-passmore's answer because it directly answers my question. But, I am actually going to use your solution (the first one) because that is a nicer UX, I think.